# I don't know how to add stepper in this checkoutpage i have tried many combinations but no output

Tags: reactjs, stepper

## Need to add stepper

```
function CheckoutSteps({step1, step2, step3, step4}) {
  return (
    <Nav className="justify-content-center mb-4">
      <Nav.Item>
        {step1? (
          <LinkContainer to="/login">
            <Nav.Link>Login</Nav.Link>
          </LinkContainer>
        ) : (
          <Nav.Link disabled>Login</Nav.Link>
        )}
      </Nav.Item>

      <Nav.Item>
        {step2? (
          <LinkContainer to="/shipping">
            <Nav.Link>Shipping</Nav.Link>
          </LinkContainer>
        ) : (
          <Nav.Link disabled>Shipping</Nav.Link>
        )}
      </Nav.Item>

      <Nav.Item>
        {step3? (
          <LinkContainer to="/payment">
            <Nav.Link>Payment</Nav.Link>
          </LinkContainer>
        ) : (
          <Nav.Link disabled>Payment</Nav.Link>
        )}
      </Nav.Item>

      <Nav.Item>
        {step4? (
          <LinkContainer to="/placeorder">
            <Nav.Link>Place Order</Nav.Link>
          </LinkContainer>
        ) : (
          <Nav.Link disabled>Place Order</Nav.Link>
        )}
      </Nav.Item>
    </Nav>
  );
}

export default CheckoutSteps;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.